# What Ruby HTTP daemon powers Heroku Bamboo apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've managed to figure out that in Aspen it was a version of Thin, and Cedar it is whatever you want it to be... What is it on Bamboo? Can you change it via the Gemfile or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the Heroku documentation says:

> On Bamboo all web process are served with Thin

Source: [Migrating to the Celadon Cedar Stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration#choose_app_server)

And from what I read into that, you can't change it. Flexbility of that kind is reserved for the more recent Cedar stack.

Comment: Thanks awendt, but I'm looking for what the *Ruby* daemon is.

Comment: You didn't really tell me if I can change it. I assume no. Accepted anyway tho.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see that. I'll add it to the answer!